# How to call method in class loaded assembly that pauses a

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, .net-assembly

I load my assembly dynamically, I create an instance of a UserControl View through Activator.CreateInstance.

```
classType = a.GetType(assembly + "." + constructor);
obj = Activator.CreateInstance(classType);
```

I have a ViewModel linked to the view. The ViewModel has a timer which it starts in the constructor.

I would like to dynamically call a method like Pause() and Resume() that stops and starts this timer.

My thoughts are that this method will have to be in the View's code-behind. I will keep the classType and obj around, so I can call the View's methods. However the way to go about informing the ViewModel to pause or resume from the code-behind without upsetting the MVVM is stumping me. Could use some advice.

**[EDIT]** 
Ignore below has been open as a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572205/how-call-dispose-method-with-loaded-assembly

If I would like to dispose of an instance of this class. I have tried

```
var methodInfo = CurrentAssemblyClassType.GetMethod("Dispose");
var methodInfo = CurrentAssemblyClassType.GetMethod("Close");
```

methodInfo is null on both, not sure what to call.

```
public partial class Blank : UserControl, IDisposable
{
    public Blank(String key)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
        }
    }

    ~Blank()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Close();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Surely you just have `ICommand`'s for Pause and Resume on your VM and bind to these from your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVVM, the View can tell the ViewModel what to do by way of "Commands"

There is nothing special about the assembly being dynamically loaded

Comment: Fair enough, if I could just ask one more question relating more about calling a method. See [EDIT] above

Comment: @Hank please open that as a separate question with appropriate title/tags